# How to fetch the files generated inside a docker image in app path in gitlab.ci [ golang ]

Tags: go, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have written a gitlab ci file in which a stage looks like

```
test:
  stage: checks
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build -t $serviceName -f file.qc
```

the `file.qc` sets few env variale and dep installation and calls a shell script ( .sh )
this script has some execution and creates a xml file

now, i need to look upon this .xml file for which to go to way is to write an artifact but the issue is that the xml file is created on a path `build/xyz/file.xml` since it runs on a docker container but in the gitlab ci file I dont have a direct way to access this file ( fyi, the directory where I am running the scripts would be something like  GOPATH/src/path/to/my/repository )

I am not sure on what changes I can make here to be able to access the file generated

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the file as an `artifact` which will allow you to view the file on the job or pipeline pages. This also allows you to fetch via http. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#create-job-artifacts

You can also pass the file between jobs using `dependencies`.